# Create a matrix of tf-idf values from documents

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, text-mining, information-retrieval

I have a set of `documents` like:

```
D1 = "The sky is blue."
D2 = "The sun is bright."
D3 = "The sun in the sky is bright."
```

and a set of `words` like:

```
"sky","land","sea","water","sun","moon"
```

I want to create a matrix like this:

```
   x        D1           D2         D3
sky         tf-idf       0          tf-idf
land        0            0          0
sea         0            0          0
water       0            0          0
sun         0            tf-idf     tf-idf
moon        0            0          0
```

Something like the example table given here: http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring14/compsci290/assignments/lab02.html. In the given link, it uses the same words from the document but I need to use the set of `words` that I have mentioned.

If the particular word is present in the document then I put the `tf-idf` values, else I put a `0` in the matrix.

Any idea how I might build some sort of matrix like this? Python will be best but R also appreciated.

I am using the following code but am not sure whether I am doing the right thing or not. My code is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


train_set = "The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.", "The sun in the sky is bright." #Documents
test_set = ["sky","land","sea","water","sun","moon"] #Query
stopWords = stopwords.words('english')

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopWords)
#print vectorizer
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
#print transformer

trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
testVectorizerArray = vectorizer.transform(test_set).toarray()
#print 'Fit Vectorizer to train set', trainVectorizerArray
#print 'Transform Vectorizer to test set', testVectorizerArray

transformer.fit(trainVectorizerArray)
#print
#print transformer.transform(trainVectorizerArray).toarray()

transformer.fit(testVectorizerArray)
#print 
tfidf = transformer.transform(testVectorizerArray)
print tfidf.todense()
```

I am getting very absurd results like this (values are only `0` and `1` while I am expecting values between 0 and 1).

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

I am also open to other libraries for calculating `tf-idf`. I just want a correct matrix which I mentioned above.

Comment: Just FYI, you can (at least on sklearn 0.18) tell the vectorizer to avoid stopwords by doing using kwarg `stop_words='english'` directly, without the need to use NLTK.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html) or [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

Code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


train_set = ["The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.", "The sun in the sky is bright."]
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

transformer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)
transformer.fit_transform(train_set).todense()
```

After fitting the model, you can transform your out of sample documents.

```
transformer.transform(test_set).todense()
```

*However*, it sounds like what you really want to do given your comments is evaluate the tf-idf of the original documents in terms of the "`test_set`" as the vocabulary? It's unclear to me what you're after I guess. If that's the case though then something like

```
transformer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, vocabulary=test_set)
transformer.fit_transform(train_set).todense().T
```

Gives you what you want I think.

Comment: I have already done that before and I am getting some weird results. See my edited question.

Comment: Well, you don't actually follow the instructions at your link or mine... See edited answer.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. By using your method, I am getting an output of `4 columns` which corresponds to `sky, blue, sun, bright` and `3 rows` which corresponds to the 3 documents. I need to find the `tf-idf` values of an external set of words, not the words that appear only in the document. If I use your method, then how can I know whether the external set of words contains words that are already in the document?

Comment: Yes, after you fit the model, you use the transform method on your test data. Why do you expect values that aren't 1? In your test set, the documents all contain one word and the default for TfidfVectorizer is to normalize the documents so that the l2 norm of the documents is 1.

Comment: Now it is confusing. Can you elaborate your answer so that I can finally get a matrix as I have displayed in my question?

Comment: If I do `print transformer.transform(test_set)` then I get the following error: `raise ValueError("Vocabulary wasn't fitted or is empty!")
ValueError: Vocabulary wasn't fitted or is empty!`

Comment: First you fit the transformer on your training set. Then you can compute the tf-idf on the out of sample documents. It's not clear to me what exactly you want to do but re-reading your question it sounds like you really want to do is use your 'test_set' as a vocabulary. See edits in answer.

Comment: As I also said before, this error indicates that you have not fit the model using the training set. You can't evaluate it on test_set without fitting the model first using either fit or fit_transform. Please see my answer and the examples in the documentation of scikit-learn.

Comment: What I want is to check whether the words in `test_set` occurs in `the documents`. If it occurs then I calculate the `tf-idf` values.

Comment: Right. So what you actually want to do is use test_set as your vocabulary. Please see my answer. It shows you how to do this.

Comment: Your answer is totally now confusing me. Can you revert back to the old version where you had both versions written.

Comment: I didn't remove any code.